# Orientdb - query in multiple databases

Tags: orientdb

I need create a query using multiples Orientdb Databases.

Ex:
I tried something like that in database1.

`select from vertex1 where field1 in ( select field2 from database2:vertex2)`

Is It possibly create a SQL query in OrientdbDB using multiples database?

Comment: Do you mean multiple databases? It's not possible.

Comment: Yes, I do. Thank you.